# Is control theory too abstract?

Tags: control

What do engineers think about the application of control theory? Is it exaggerated? Is the math too overwhelming for real life application?

Comment: Think about it this way. I have a control system I developed that roughly works for my application, what tools can I use to model it to determine a) potential improvement options and b) critical elements of my system. You turn to the theory to ground you and formalize your work. Research engineers develop proof of concept or niche applications for complex control systems, this takes time to propagate through another field that may benefit from it, an established formal theoretical framework is required for that to even start happening

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For most real-life applications (read 90-95%), a PID (proportional,integral,derivative) controller in a feedback loop is sufficient. Although there is a lot of research done on things like self-tuning controllers and advanced theory for specific applications like flying supersonic aircraft, a high proportion of controls problems can be solved without many of the advanced techniques.

It can be the case that the calculations for some control algorithms is too complicated for the computer involved, but oftentimes the main reason that engineers stick with PID is that the improvements from more advanced solutions aren't needed- they might only need to hand tune the controller gains once and then the system response is good enough that they can forget about it.

Source: I'm in graduate school for mechanical engineering/robotics.

Comment: Where do you go to buy a PID controller and does that mean most advanced control theory such as say predictive control, intelligent is largely useless?

Comment: "PID controller" is a catch-all phrase to describe something that tells a system (eg. motor) what to do. Usually this something is a computer running a PID algorithm. For more info: [Brian Douglas's control theory videos.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=14&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CHoQtwIwDWoVChMIiLCH94vaxgIVjCmICh0cCQAT&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DUR0hOmjaHp0&ei=dbmkVcihIYzToASckoCYAQ&usg=AFQjCNF4vHWmCptZMdDrOGJ-KuQbIq38SQ&sig2=L3ENycAxk8_3DosDHCeY8w)

I don't mean to say advanced controls are useless- it's VERY useful in certain situations.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not. Theory in Engineering is devolped as applications become more complex and allows the design of things that otherwise would be impossible.

Answer (score 0):

No - it is a basic tool also in the field of electronics. Each working amplifier needs negative feedback (effective for DC only or for DC and AC). Think of operational amplifiers which cannot work without negative feedback. However, in this context it is important to know **(a)** that (and how) negative feedback degrades dynamic stability (phase margin) and **(b)** how the tendency to instability can be reduced - for example, with the help of a BODE diagram. Here we make use of the classical rules and tools of control theory (loop gain, phase compensation, pole-zero cancellation, stability margin,...)